# Improve efficiency matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, parfor

I have a matlab code that is very inefficient and I need to run it several times. 
The code is basically a big `parfor loop` which I guess there is almost impossible to get around.

The code starts by loading several parameters and 4-D matrices, and then needs to make a few interpolations. All need to be done 5000 times (thus the parfor loop).

Here is how the code look like. I simplified the code the most I could without taking out the key ingredients.

```
load file

nsim = 5000
T = 12; 
N = 1000;

cumQx = cumsum(Qx);
cumQz = cumsum(Qz);
cumQs = cumsum(Qs);

for k=1:nsim
st(k).ksim    = kstar*ones(N, T);
st(k).Vsim  = zeros(N,T);  
st(k).Psim = zeros(N,T);   
end


parfor k = 1:nsim    

    sysrand  = rand(T, 1);
    idiorand = rand(N, T);
    sigmarand = rand(T,1);

    xid = zeros(T, 1);
    zid = zeros(N, T);
    sid = zeros(T,1);
    xid(1) = 8;
    zid(:, 1) = 5;
    sid(1) = 1;
    % Initializing the simulation

    simx    = zeros(T,1);
    zsim    = ones(N,T)*zbar;
    simsx    = zeros(T,1);

    % Construct 3-D grid using 'ndgrid'
    [ks,zs] = ndgrid(kgrid,z);

    for j = 2:T
            sid(j) = find(cumQs(:, sid(j-1)) >= sigmarand(j), 1); 
            simsx(j-1) = sigmax(sid(j));

             xid(j) = find(cumQx(:, xid(j-1)) >= sysrand(j), 1); 
             simx(j-1) = x(xid(j));

             for n = 1:N
                 zid(n, j)   = find(cumQz(:, zid(n, j-1)) >= idiorand(n, j), 1); 
                 zsim(n,j-1) = z(zid(n, j));
             end
            st(k).ksim(:,j)      = interpn(ks, zs , squeeze(kprime(:,xid(j),:,sid(j))),   st(k).ksim(:,j-1),zsim(:,j-1),'linear');       % K
            st(k).Vsim(:,j)      = interpn(ks, zs , squeeze(V(:,xid(j),:,sid(j))),        st(k).ksim(:,j-1),zsim(:,j-1),'linear');       % V
            st(k).Psim(:,j)      = interpn(ks, zs , squeeze(P(:,xid(j),:,sid(j))),        st(k).ksim(:,j-1),zsim(:,j-1),'linear');       % P


    end; 

end
```

Here is a link for the matrices needed to run the code: http://www.filedropper.com/file_406

Is there any better way of doing this that would significantly reduce the computation time? My guess is no ... 
Ideally there woul be a way of vectorizing the k = 1:nsim loop.

Comment: You may want to ask to [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to time and test your code, I removed the parfor loop and replaced it with a for loop, then used the MATLAB profiler. I used `nsims = 500` for the purpose of my tests.

Using the profiler, I found two key bottlenecks in your code. The first is the `find()` function in the most nested for loop (n-loop). The second is the three calls to the `interpn()` function. **Those 4 lines use +88% of the computation time.** [image]

The `find` function is slower than desirable in this circumstance due to the overhead of the function call (especially considering the number of calls it receives in the nested loops), as well as the built-in error checking and management. Replacing the `find` function with a hard-coded binary search (below) greatly improves performance, and this was only replacing the `find` in the n-loop. Using `find` for `nsims = 500` resulted in a run time of **29.8** seconds. Using the binary search, the run time was **12.1** seconds.Note: this only works because your data is sorted, this code cannot replace find in every instance. **EDIT:** Using the alternate approach in the other answer by @EBH is a cleaner way to do this.

```
%perform binary search (same as your find function)
searchVal=idiorand(n, j);
il = 1;
iu = sizeCumQZ; % should be defined outside the loop as size(cumQz,1)
while (il+1<iu)
    lw=floor((il+iu)/2); % split the upper index
    if cumQz(lw,zid(n, j-1)) >= searchVal
        iu=lw; % decrease lower_index_b (whose x value remains \geq to lower bound)
    else
        il=lw; % increase lower_index_a (whose x value remains less than lower bound)
    end
end
if cumQz(il,zid(n, j-1))>=searchVal
    zid(n,j) = il;
else
    zid(n,j) = iu;
end
```

The `interpn` function is considerably slowed by method checking, error management and data format management. The roughly 100 lines of code used in the standard `interpn` can be cut down to 2 lines per call and significantly increase performance by knowing we only need one type of interpolation, and that our data conforms to a specific format. To do this we use the `griddedInterpolant` function directly (see below).  Again with `nsims = 500`, using the `interpn` function (still using the un-changed `find` code) has a run time of **29.8** seconds. Using the refined method, below, decreased run time to **20.4** seconds.

Refined method replaces the calls to `interp`, shown here

```
st(k).ksim(:,j)      = interpn(ks, zs , squeeze(kprime(:,xid(j),:,sid(j))),   st(k).ksim(:,j-1),zsim(:,j-1),'linear');       % K
st(k).Vsim(:,j)      = interpn(ks, zs , squeeze(V(:,xid(j),:,sid(j))),        st(k).ksim(:,j-1),zsim(:,j-1),'linear');       % V
st(k).Psim(:,j)      = interpn(ks, zs , squeeze(P(:,xid(j),:,sid(j))),        st(k).ksim(:,j-1),zsim(:,j-1),'linear');       % P
```

with more direct calls to `griddedInterpolant`, shown here:

```
F = griddedInterpolant(ks,zs,squeeze(kprime(:,xid(j),:,sid(j))), 'linear','none');
st(k).ksim(:,j) = F(st(k).ksim(:,j-1),zsim(:,j-1));

F = griddedInterpolant(ks,zs,squeeze(V(:,xid(j),:,sid(j))), 'linear','none');
st(k).Vsim(:,j) = F(st(k).ksim(:,j-1),zsim(:,j-1));

F = griddedInterpolant(ks,zs,squeeze(P(:,xid(j),:,sid(j))), 'linear','none');
st(k).Psim(:,j) = F(st(k).ksim(:,j-1),zsim(:,j-1));
```

Combining the binary search instead of `find` with the calls to `griddedInterpolant` instead of `interpn` reduces the total run time to **3.8** seconds, a nearly 8x improvement over initial run time.

Three further points of note:

1) I would recommend following the advice outlined in previous answers, specifically staying away from structures if possible and moving whatever you can out of the loops (specifically the ndgrid, as this most certainly only needs to be run one time).

2) I noticed that, when using `nsims=5000`, the total memory used during this script is near 2.5gigs. If this is near your system's total available memory, this could result in significant slowdown. In this case I would recommend performing smaller batches of calculations, saving out the results, and then proceeding with further calculations.

3)Finally, during my tests, using parfor was actually slower than using the standard for loop. I beleive this is because each individual loop is a relatively short operation in this instance, and the overhead associated with designating parallel jobs and managing the cluster workers outweighs the gains from parallel processing. This may not be the case if you are on a large computer cluster, but on my single (4-core) machine, `parfor` only resulted in slow-down. I would recommend testing each case for yourself,with your actual working code, after you have made the recommended changes above if you care to.

The full code changes I made are shown below, these do not include any changes in the use of structs or other small optimizations that would still be recommended.

```
load file

tic;

nsim = 500
T = 12; 
N = 1000;

searchVal=1;
il = 1;
iu = 1;

cumQx = cumsum(Qx);
cumQz = cumsum(Qz);
cumQs = cumsum(Qs);

sizeCumQZ = size(cumQz,1);

for k=1:nsim
st(k).ksim    = kstar*ones(N, T);
st(k).Vsim  = zeros(N,T);  
st(k).Psim = zeros(N,T);   
end

%was parfor
for k = 1:nsim    

    sysrand  = rand(T, 1);
    idiorand = rand(N, T);
    sigmarand = rand(T,1);

    xid = zeros(T, 1);
    zid = zeros(N, T);
    sid = zeros(T,1);
    xid(1) = 8;
    zid(:, 1) = 5;
    sid(1) = 1;
    % Initializing the simulation

    simx    = zeros(T,1);
    zsim    = ones(N,T)*zbar;
    simsx    = zeros(T,1);

    % Construct 3-D grid using 'ndgrid'
    [ks,zs] = ndgrid(kgrid,z);

    for j = 2:T
            sid(j) = find(cumQs(:, sid(j-1)) >= sigmarand(j), 1); 
            simsx(j-1) = sigmax(sid(j));

             xid(j) = find(cumQx(:, xid(j-1)) >= sysrand(j), 1); 
             simx(j-1) = x(xid(j));

             for n = 1:N
                 %perform binary search (same as your find function)
                 searchVal=idiorand(n, j);
                 il = 1;
                 iu = sizeCumQZ;
                 while (il+1<iu)
                     lw=floor((il+iu)/2); % split the upper index
                     if cumQz(lw,zid(n, j-1)) >= searchVal
                         iu=lw; % decrease lower_index_b (whose x value remains \geq to lower bound)
                     else
                         il=lw; % increase lower_index_a (whose x value remains less than lower bound)
                     end
                 end
                 if cumQz(il,zid(n, j-1))>=searchVal
                     zid(n,j) = il;
                 else
                     zid(n,j) = iu;
                 end
                 zsim(n,j-1) = z(zid(n,j));
             end

             F = griddedInterpolant(ks,zs,squeeze(kprime(:,xid(j),:,sid(j))), 'linear','none');
             st(k).ksim(:,j) = F(st(k).ksim(:,j-1),zsim(:,j-1));

             F = griddedInterpolant(ks,zs,squeeze(V(:,xid(j),:,sid(j))), 'linear','none');
             st(k).Vsim(:,j) = F(st(k).ksim(:,j-1),zsim(:,j-1));

             F = griddedInterpolant(ks,zs,squeeze(P(:,xid(j),:,sid(j))), 'linear','none');
             st(k).Psim(:,j) = F(st(k).ksim(:,j-1),zsim(:,j-1));

    end;

end
toc;
```

**EDIT:** Messing around with the `griddedInterpolant` a bit more, I was able to eek out an additional 15% speed increase by combining the three interpolants into one through concatenation of the grids and values for the K, V, and P interpolants. At the top of the code, best done outside the loop, I replaced the original grid creation with:

```
zRange = max(z(:))-min(z(:))+1;
zzzGrid = [z;z+1*zRange;z+2*zRange];% for K, V, and P 
[ksBig,zsBig] = ndgrid(kgrid,zzzGrid);
nZ = numel(z); %used below
valGrid = zeros(size(ksBig)); %used below
```

And replace the  3 calls to `griddedInterpolant` with:

```
valGrid(:,1:nZ) = squeeze(kprime(:,xid(j),:,sid(j)));%K
valGrid(:,nZ+1:2*nZ) = squeeze(V(:,xid(j),:,sid(j)));%V
valGrid(:,2*nZ+1:3*nZ) = squeeze(P(:,xid(j),:,sid(j)));%P

F = griddedInterpolant(ksBig,zsBig,valGrid, 'linear','none');

st(k).ksim(:,j) = F(st(k).ksim(:,j-1),zsim(:,j-1));
st(k).Vsim(:,j) = F(st(k).ksim(:,j-1),zsim(:,j-1)+zRange);
st(k).Psim(:,j) = F(st(k).ksim(:,j-1),zsim(:,j-1)+2*zRange);
```

Or if we are OK trading a more convoluted setup for a 19% increase instead of a 15% increase, we can move the `griddedInterpolant` outside of the j loop altogether. At the beginning of the code, setup the grid as such:

```
zRange = max(z(:))-min(z(:))+1;
zzzGrid = [z;z+1*zRange;z+2*zRange];
zzzRange =  max(zzzGrid(:))-min(zzzGrid(:))+1;
zzzTGrid = [];
for j = 2:T
   zzzTGrid(end+1:end+numel(zzzGrid)) = zzzGrid+(j-2)*zzzRange;
end
[ksBig,zsBig] = ndgrid(kgrid,zzzTGrid);
nZ = numel(z); %used below
valGrid = zeros(size(ksBig)); %used below
```

And replace the previous `griddedInterpolant` as shown below:

```
for j = 2:T
    %%%%%
    %...
    %Other code in the j loop
    %...
    %%%%%
    valGrid(:,(1:nZ)+3*nZ*(j-2)) = squeeze(kprime(:,xid(j),:,sid(j)));%K
    valGrid(:,(nZ+1:2*nZ)+3*nZ*(j-2)) = squeeze(V(:,xid(j),:,sid(j)));%V
    valGrid(:,(2*nZ+1:3*nZ)+3*nZ*(j-2)) = squeeze(P(:,xid(j),:,sid(j)));%P
end;

F = griddedInterpolant(ksBig,zsBig,valGrid, 'linear','none');

for j = 2:T
    st(k).ksim(:,j) = F(stTest(k).ksim(:,j-1),zsim(:,j-1)+3*zRange*(j-2));
    st(k).Vsim(:,j) = F(stTest(k).ksim(:,j-1),zsim(:,j-1)+zRange+3*zRange*(j-2));
    st(k).Psim(:,j) = F(stTest(k).ksim(:,j-1),zsim(:,j-1)+2*zRange+3*zRange*(j-2));
end
```

And if we want to get even pickier (2% speed increase), we can replace all calls to `squeeze` with a version that does no error checking, `mySqueeze` instead:

```
function b = mySqueeze(a)
%Trimmed down version of squeeze, a built-in MATLAB function, has no error-managment or case optimization
  siz = size(a);
  siz(siz==1) = []; % Remove singleton dimensions.
  siz = [siz ones(1,2-length(siz))]; % Make sure siz is at least 2-D
  b = reshape(a,siz);
```

Comment: +1 You have a raise a good point with `interpn`. Have a look at my answer for another faster option to replace `find` without assuming the data is sorted.

Comment: @EBH Thats a creative vectorization of the find operation, +1 for you too!

Answer (score 4):

1. Try not to use structs, this will also make your code vectorizable (where it's possible) more easily.

At the start of your code, replace:

```
for k=1:nsim
    st(k).ksim = kstar*ones(N, T);
    st(k).Vsim = zeros(N,T);
    st(k).Psim = zeros(N,T);
end
```

with:

```
ksim = kstar*ones(N,T,nsim);
Vsim = zeros(N,T,nsim);
Psim = zeros(N,T,nsim);
```

then at the end instead of calling `st`, call:

```
ksim(:,j,k) = interpn(ks,zs,squeeze(kprime(:,xid(j),:,sid(j))),ksim(:,j-1,k),zsim(:,j-1),'linear');
Vsim(:,j,k) = interpn(ks,zs,squeeze(V(:,xid(j),:,sid(j))),     Vsim(:,j-1,k),zsim(:,j-1),'linear');
Psim(:,j,k) = interpn(ks,zs,squeeze(P(:,xid(j),:,sid(j))),     Psim(:,j-1,k),zsim(:,j-1),'linear');
```

If needed you can put all the three variables inside a struct after the loop ends.

2. Take out from the loop all the random generators.

Before the loop write:

```
sysrand = rand(T,nsim);
idiorand = rand(N, T,nsim);
sigmarand = rand(T,nsim);
```

and then replace inside the loop:

```
sigmarand(j) --> sigmarand(j,k)
sysrand(j) --> sysrand(j,k)
idiorand(n,j) --> idiorand(n,j,k)
```

3. Vectorize the most inner for loop:

replace:

```
for n = 1:N
    zid(n,j)   = find(cumQz(:, zid(n, j-1)) >= idiorand(n,j), 1);
    zsim(n,j-1) = z(zid(n, j));
end
```

with:

```
cumQz_k = cumQz(:, zid(:, j-1)).';
pos = bsxfun(@ge,cumQz_k,idiorand(:,j));
zid(:,j) = (sum(~cumsum(pos'))+1).';
zsim(:,j-1) = z(zid(:, j));
```

**This will give you a significant boost of up to 90% for that process and 60% overall**. all other things being equal (but not using `parfor`), with `nsim = 200` the whole simulation with the for loop took **16s**, from them 10s dedicated for this loop. After vectorization, the simulation took only **6s**, from them about one second for the alternative vectorization approach.

---

Using all the remarks above, including the use of `griddedInterpolant` suggested in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39086802/2627163), will bring you to 5000 in less than a minute, so it's better not to use `parfor`, which will probably slow it down because of overhead communication (i.e. using a lot of memory).

Here is the final code (note that I replaced your `j` with `t`):

```
nsim = 5000;
T = 12;
N = 1000;
cumQx = cumsum(Qx);
cumQz = cumsum(Qz);
cumQs = cumsum(Qs);
ksim = kstar*ones(N,T,nsim);
Vsim = zeros(N,T,nsim);
Psim = zeros(N,T,nsim);
sysrand = rand(T,nsim);
idiorand = rand(N,T,nsim);
sigmarand = rand(T,nsim);
% Construct 3-D grid using 'ndgrid'
[ks,zs] = ndgrid(kgrid,z);

for k = 1:nsim
    % Initializing the simulation:
    xid = [8; zeros(T-1, 1)];
    zid = [ones(N,1)*5 zeros(N,T-1)];
    alter = [ones(N,1)*5 zeros(N,T-1)];
    sid = [1; zeros(T-1,1)];
    simx = zeros(T,1);
    zsim = ones(N,T)*zbar;
    simsx = zeros(T,1);

    for t = 2:T
        sid(t) = find(cumQs(:, sid(t-1)) >= sigmarand(t,k), 1);
        simsx(t-1) = sigmax(sid(t));

        xid(t) = find(cumQx(:, xid(t-1)) >= sysrand(t,k), 1);
        simx(t-1) = x(xid(t));

        cumQz_k = cumQz(:, zid(:, t-1)).';
        pos = bsxfun(@ge,cumQz_k,idiorand(:,t,k));
        zid(:,t) = (sum(~cumsum(pos'))+1).';
        zsim(:,t-1) = z(zid(:, t));

        F = griddedInterpolant(ks,zs,squeeze(kprime(:,xid(t),:,sid(t))), 'linear','none');
        ksim(:,t,k) = F(ksim(:,t-1,k),zsim(:,t-1));
        F = griddedInterpolant(ks,zs,squeeze(V(:,xid(t),:,sid(t))), 'linear','none');
        Vsim(:,t,k) = F(ksim(:,t-1,k),zsim(:,t-1));
        F = griddedInterpolant(ks,zs,squeeze(P(:,xid(t),:,sid(t))), 'linear','none');
        Psim(:,t,k) = F(ksim(:,t-1,k),zsim(:,t-1));

    end
end
```

You are most welcome to ask in the comments for any unclear parts of the code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I started with that exactly, but that does not allow for parfor which was yielding a huge improvement in speed given the no vectorization.

Comment: @volcompt see my edited answer for a workaround, this may take one step further in vectorizing what's possible.

Comment: Thanks. I will run it. My guess is that it will be just a slight improvement in performance, but I will post the appropriate tic/tocs. 
I still think that putting the simulation in a function might not help if the end goal is to vectorize along the nsim dimension.
I am working on a draft of such a code. If I manage to get it I will post it here.

Comment: @volcompt 1) for timing you better use [`timeit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html). 2) while moving the simulation to a different function you also change your output from structure to matrix, this should bring some improvement. 3) I think you should try vectorizing the simulation function first, and leave the `nsim` dimension to the `parfor`.

Comment: I upvoted it. I guess the ideal answer would vectorize the k=1:nsim loop.
I am working on it, and I think I am not that far away of getting it. If I get it, I will post the solution here.

Comment: @volcompt see my last edit (topic 3). I think you can vectorize most of it.

Comment: Thanks! I guess your code plus the idea above of using griddedinterpolant shall do the trick! I will leave this open a few more days and then accept the answer and give the reputation (can I share it between two answers?)

Comment: Using all the tweaks already found, I have cut down the time by **8** (from 16s to 2s while `nsim = 200`), so now it take less than a minute for 5000 simulations (without `parfor`), and I think you better use just `for`. I'll continue edit my answer to include all the changes I did. You can share a bounty, but you can award it twice in a question. However, the answer have to be posted (or at least edited?) after you set the bounty.

Comment: Alright! Sounds fair! I will award two bounties then! I appreciate very much if you keep editing your answer. Let me know once you are done.

Comment: Well, I think that's all. There may be some other elements that can be vectorized, but their running time is insignificant. So that's probably the best result you can get, and it's quick enough to work with. Good luck!

Comment: Great! Thank you very much! I will leave the bounty here for a few more days, in case someone else wants to give it a go and then award the two bounties as promised.

Comment: Btw, on line 29 shouldnt it be sigmarand(t,k)? And so on for the remaining variables?

Comment: Yes, off course, this is a remaining from the function `one_sim` I wrote before... I'll edit this.

Answer (score 0):

Higher level optimization aside (the code seems vectorizable, but I don't know without running it myself), you're doing a lot of unnecessary computations / memory reallocations inside your loop.

Do you *really* need to zero `xid`, `zid`, `sid`, `simx`, `zsim`, and `simsx`? It doesn't really hurt if they have garbage values or zeros, since you only access the current index every time. Not to mention, you probably save yourself a huge memory allocation operation from not zeroing.

Also, there' no real need to recalculate the ndgrid.

Move all those things outside your loop.

Comment: on second thought, the zeros may be necessary due to the parallel nature of the access ... but the ndgrid can definitely go outside.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I definitely can move the ndgrid outside. But that does not significantly improve efficiency. I tried to get my head around of making it vectorizable, but couldn t figure it out ...